# Passar um List como parâmetro em web services RESTFul Java

Tags: java, json, web-service, lista, restful

Alguém poderia me explicar como receber um List como parâmetro em um webservices RESTFul Java ?
Já procurei em diversos lugares, mas ainda não consegui compreender.
Agradeço desde já !
O código abaixo é um exemplo e como fiz no meu código real.
Na requisição, encaminho um JSON com os produtos, o web-services retorna 200 OK, mas imprime "[]".

```
@path("/incluirProdutos")
@consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String incluirProdutos(List<Produto> produtos){ 

      return produtos.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Bom Dia, 
Isto mesmo, como ali no código. Não sei se isto é possível. Seria ?

Comment: Pretendo fazer o server e o client, então, vou fazer tudo em Java. Entretanto, poderia falar um pouco mais sobre como seria a aplicabilidade da serialização do objeto, neste contexto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução para isso é usar uma classe para o "wrap" da sua lista, segue um exemplo abaixo para ajudar você:

```
// Wrapper
class Produtos {
  List<Produto> produtos
}

// JAX-RS
@path("/incluirProdutos")
@consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String incluirProdutos(Produtos produtos){ 

      return produtos.toString();
}

// JSON
{
  "produtos": [
    {
      "nome": "teste"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Leonardo, Java não tem um recurso deste tipo nativo ? É sempre necessário recorrer a esta solução ?

Comment: Normalmente é o que está sendo usado, talvez em versões mais novas isso mude.

Se a reposta te ajudou não esqueça de marcar ela como util e aceita.